# Change children color div when click parent div | CSS Pseudo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I dont know much about css.

I have **`_sideButton`** with **default color `white`**

```
._sideButton{background-color:white;height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:5px}

._sideButton:active{background-color:red;height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:5px}
```

- How when we choose BUTTON 2, the `_sideButton` turns red, and always becomes red.
- When selecting BUTTON 1, BUTTON 1 `_sideButton` turns red, then BUTTON2 `_sideButton` becomes default (white).

***Here** === [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6mL7h5mL/) ===

Thx Before -/-

```css
/*** Here guys ***/
._sideButton{background-color:white;height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:5px}

._sideButton:active{background-color:red;height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:5px}



._tabFolder{background-color:rgba(29, 33, 41, 1); cursor:pointer;position:relative;}
._tabFolder:hover{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1)}
._tabFolder:active{background-color:rgba(29, 33, 41, 1)}

._itemPosition{align-items:center;display:flex}

._5bme ._sideFolder{background-color:#066cd2}
._iconText:hover ._1i5y,.uiPopover.selected ._1i5y{display:block}
._iconText{align-items:center;display:flex;justify-content:space-between;width:100%;margin-left:13px;}
```

```html
<body style="background:grey;">
    <div class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" role="presentation" style="height: 40px;  user-select: none;">
            <div class="_sideButton"></div>
            <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
            <span style="color:white;">BUTTON 1</span>
            </div>
            </div>


<div class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" role="presentation" style="height: 40px;  user-select: none;">
            <div class="_sideButton"></div>
            <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
            <span style="color:white;">BUTTON 2</span>
            </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can't do this with pure css. use javascript

Comment: @scroobius You mean it's impossible to turn the button red and keep it that way with only CSS? Then how did this happen?: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/764k6qo0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CSS you can hide `<input type='checkbox'` or `'radio'>` and use `<label for=`'ID OF RADIO/CHECKBOX'`></label>`. The label would act as the button while the chx/rad would be placed before the label and would keep the label's "state" persistent (ex. change to red and stay red indefinitely.) The state would be determined by whether the rad/.chx was **[`:checked`](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)**.

#### Example

```
.radio:checked + .label { color:red }
```

A *.radio* button is **:checked** and right after it **+** is a *.label* that text turns *red*. The **+** is an [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and you may so this as well: **~** [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

You can also use the [**`:target` selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors/Using_the_:target_pseudo-class_in_selectors). Take an `<a>`nchor tag assign its `href` attribute the value of in element's `#id`. Then assign the element a `:target` selector. Similar to the rad/chx & label combo, it allows us to use CSS to change an elements style dynamically and keep it persistent.

Although the demo shows an "older" sibling (i.e. radio button) and "younger: sibling (i.e. label) relationship, this demo can easily work in a parent child relationship as well (hint: remove **+**). Note there's no required relationship that needs to be between an `<a>` and `element:target` (other than that they both have to be on the same document.

### References

[**Checkbox/Radio Button & Label Hack**](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

[**`:target` selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors/Using_the_:target_pseudo-class_in_selectors).

#### Modified OP: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/764k6qo0/

### Demo

```css
/* Radio Buttons & Labels */


/* :checked & for='ID OF RADIO' */

.rad {
  display: none
}

.lab {
  border-radius: 9px;
  border: 2px inset grey;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px 10px;
}

.lab::before {
  content: 'WHITE';
}

.rad:checked+.lab {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.rad:checked+.lab::before {
  content: '\a0\a0RED\a0\a0';
}


/* Anchor & Any Element */


/* href='#ID OF ELEMENT' &  #ANY:target */

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: yellow;
  background: #000;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

a:first-of-type {
  color: #ff4c4c
}

a:nth-of-type {
  color: yellow
}

a:last-of-type {
  color: lime
}

b {
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 3px outset grey;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}

#T1:target {
  background: red;
}

#T2:target {
  background: yellow
}

#T3:target {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<input id='R1' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
<label id='L1' class='lab' for='R1'></label>

<input id='R2' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
<label id='L2' class='lab' for='R2'></label>

<input id='R3' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
<label id='L3' class='lab' for='R3'></label>

<hr>

<a href='#T1' target='_self'>STOP</a>
<a href='#T2' target='_self'>SLOW</a>
<a href='#T3' target='_self'>GO</a>


<b id='T1'>&nbsp;</b>
<b id='T2'>&nbsp;</b>
<b id='T3'>&nbsp;</b>
```