# How do I make a table items a radio button?

Tags: css, html-table

How do I make the each block of this image act as a radio button?

[image]

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
               <tbody>
                 <tr class="category-item">
                   <td>
                     <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="" />
                     <label for="input-1">IT Solutions</label>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="" />
                     <label for="input-1">Household</label>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="" />
                     <label for="input-1">Design &amp; Multimedia</label>
                   </td>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr class="category-item">
                   <td>
                     <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="" />
                     <label for="input-1">Event &amp; photography</label>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="" />
                     <label for="input-1">Sales &amp; Marketing</label>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="" />
                     <label for="input-1">Engineering &amp; Architecture</label>
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="category-item">
                   <td>
                     <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="" />
                     <label for="input-1">Writing &amp; Translation</label>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="" />
                     <label for="input-1">Finance &amp; Accounting</label>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="" />
                     <label for="input-1">Legal</label>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
```

I've tried this but it only alows to select one table row as a radio button.

```
.category-item input{
display: none;
}


.category-item label{
cursor: pointer;
padding: 30px;
}
```

How to make each td act as a radio button the tr tag separates the block so all the elements are not radio button.

Comment: Separate ids. Id should be unique, like this: https://www.bootply.com/K67KEukoek

Comment: I think you'd need to use some Javascript for this. Are you open to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use unique id for inputs or dont use id and set input in label like this

```
<label><input type="radio" name="list" value="" /> Label Title</label>
```

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/vmt/pen/zPwBQw), hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you did that you are using the same `id` for all inputs and this is totally wrong, because `id`s are always unique which means that no more than one element will take the same `id`.

then how you are going to determine which `radio` is `checked` right now since you are hiding the radio?

For this you could use **Pseudo Element** `:checked` to style the checked `radio`, e.g. you could change the background color for the checked radio.

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48ymo0mk/), hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Say thanks to : **zer00ne** on [My Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233534/change-children-color-div-when-click-parent-div-css-pseudo)

```css
/* Radio Buttons & Labels */


/* :checked & for='ID OF RADIO' */

.rad {
  display: none
}

.lab {
  border-radius: 9px;
  border: 2px inset grey;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px 10px;
}

.lab::before {
  content: 'WHITE';
}

.rad:checked+.lab {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.rad:checked+.lab::before {
  content: '\a0\a0RED\a0\a0';
}


/* Anchor & Any Element */


/* href='#ID OF ELEMENT' &  #ANY:target */

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: yellow;
  background: #000;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

a:first-of-type {
  color: #ff4c4c
}

a:nth-of-type {
  color: yellow
}

a:last-of-type {
  color: lime
}

b {
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 3px outset grey;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}

#T1:target {
  background: red;
}

#T2:target {
  background: yellow
}

#T3:target {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<input id='R1' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
<label id='L1' class='lab' for='R1'></label>

<input id='R2' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
<label id='L2' class='lab' for='R2'></label>

<input id='R3' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
<label id='L3' class='lab' for='R3'></label>

<hr>

<a href='#T1' target='_self'>STOP</a>
<a href='#T2' target='_self'>SLOW</a>
<a href='#T3' target='_self'>GO</a>


<b id='T1'>&nbsp;</b>
<b id='T2'>&nbsp;</b>
<b id='T3'>&nbsp;</b>
```